# Two questions on the Moore–Penrose inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares, pseudoinverse

We define the Moore–Penrose inverse of a matrix $A$ as follows

$$A^+ := \lim_{x \to 0} \, (A^T A + xI)^{-1} A^T$$

and we say that it finds the lowest norm solution of $\|Ax - y\|$. I'm not sure about 2 things:

1. Why is $(A^T A + xI)$ always invertible?
2. How does this definition imply $A^+ A = I$?

Comment: For the first question, $A^TA$ is always symmetric positive semidefinite, i.e. the eigenvalues are all $\geq 0$. So for all $x>0$, $A^TA+xI$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix since it's eigenvalues are all $\geq x>0$ and SPD matrices are all invertible.

Comment: You're using $x$ to denote both a scalar and a vector. No wonder you're confused!

Answer (score 5):

Sketch for proof of 1): if $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A^\top A$, then $\lambda_1+x, \ldots, \lambda_n + x$ are the eigenvalues of $A^\top A + x I$ (why?). Since the $\lambda_i$ are nonnegative (why?) and $x > 0$, we see that $A^\top A + x I$ has no zero eigenvalues.

---

The pseudoinverse does not satisfy $A^+ A = I$. Check the [definition/properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition) again.