# Bound on $\|A^+ z - z\|$ where $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of the matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, maxima-minima, pseudoinverse

**My question**

Can we get any bound (depending on $A$ and $z$) of $\|A^+ z - z\|$, where $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of the matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ ?

**Details**

Actually this question came from a problem I have: Given $z^\star\in \mathbb{R}^n$, I must find $\underset{z\in \text{Im} A}{\text{argmin}} \|z-z^\star\|$ (or the min), and I thought that $A^+z^\star$ could be a good candidate, or at least a good approximation.
Then I saw here ([Two questions on the Moore–Penrose inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578214/two-questions-on-the-moore-penrose-inverse)) that the Moore-Penrose inverse "finds the lowest norm solution of $\|Ax-z^\star\|$". So it seems that this is the solution. But then can we have a bound on the error we make?

Could someone help ?

Comment: Unless $m=n$, the expression $A^+z-z$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user1551 In fact. Good remark... I edit.

Answer (score 1):

The Moore-Penrose inverse can be used to obtain least squares solution to the linear system $Ax \approx b$, in the sense $x_{\mathrm{LS}} := A^{\dagger} b$ is such that $x_{\mathrm{LS}} = \mathrm{argmin}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{m}} \Vert Ax - b \Vert_2$. So the closest vector in $\mathrm{im}(A)$ to $b$ is actually $Ax_{\mathrm{LS}} = A A^{\dagger} b$. (The matrix $A A^{\dagger}$ is actually the orthogonal projection matrix onto the range of $A$; see [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse).)

In your case, you are trying to approximate $Az \approx z^{\star}$, so the closest vector in the range of $A$ to $z$ is actually $A A^{\dagger} z^{\star}$. (As mentioned in the comment, this only makes sense if $n = m$.) We have $\Vert A A^{\dagger} z^{\star} - z^{\star} \Vert_2 = \Vert (I - A A^{\dagger}) z^{\star} \Vert_2$. This is the norm of the component of $z^{\star}$ in the kernel of $A^T$ (the orthogonal complement of the range of $A$). If $A$ is full rank, then clearly this is zero since $z^{\star} \in \mathrm{im}(A)$. So suppose that $A$ is not full rank for non-triviality. Then we have the trivial bound $\Vert A A^{\dagger} z^{\star} - z^{\star} \Vert_2 \leq \Vert z^{\star} \Vert_2$, which is achieved if $z^{\star} \in \mathrm{ker}(A^T)$.

I'm not sure if we can give a more precise bound in terms of $A$ and $z$.

Comment: Why is $||AA^+z^\star - z^\star|| \leq ||z||$ trivial ? Is $|||AA^+-I|||\leq 1$ obvious ?

Comment: One way to see that is that $AA^{\dagger} - I$ is a projection operator (so it's eigenvalues are $0$ or $1$). The second is from the fact that putting in $x_{\mathrm{LS}} = A^{\dagger} z$ into the optimisation problem shows that $\Vert AA^{\dagger} z - z \Vert_2 \leq \Vert A 0 - z \Vert_2 = \Vert z \Vert_2$, since $x_{\mathrm{LS}}$ is the least squares solution by construction.

Comment: Thank you very much ! So then if $||AA^+-I||<1$, does it mean that $A$ is invertible ?

Comment: It would seem so: that condition would imply that the dimension of $\mathrm{ker}(A^T)$ is zero, and hence so is the dimension of $\mathrm{ker}(A)$.